# How to tell how long a NSOperation has been executing?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsoperation

Is there a way to tell how long a NSOperation has been executing?

```
 for (NSOperation *operation in [self.operationQueue operations]) {
     // how to tell how long the operation has been executing?
 }
```

Comment: If it's a custom subclass, just add an ivar, `startDate`.

Answer (score 1):

Make two variables, NSTimeInterval.

```
NSTimeInterval t1, t2;
```

When the operation starts you run :

```
t1 = NSTimeIntervalSince1970;
```

and when it finishes

```
t2 = NSTimeIntervalSince1970;
```

Then you simply do

```
NSTimeInterval t3 = t2 -t1;
```

No you know how many seconds this did run. This is crude and perhaps there are better ways to get exact numbers, but I would then suggest you use a profiler like Instruments.

But this is a good measure as it is quite simple and does not take away any cpu power, like a profiler would do.

I would also suggest searching standard C libraries for some cpu ticks or something close to that.

Enjoy.